2023 Community Moderator Election Results
Moderator election #2 on Bitcoin has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

They will be joining the existing crew shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!
For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results here or view a summary report online.

Thank you; it will be my pleasure to serve the Bitcoin.se community.

Congratulations on your election, Hannah! I’m looking forward to working with you. Thank you to everyone that participated in the election.
